# Nested Linq query (multiple levels)

Tags: c#, linq, nested

How can I put the following loops into one Linq query? The end result that I am trying to achieve is getting a list of Statements that are in those class methods.

Context: 
For every class, the corresponding methods are fetched with the classname. With every combination of classname / method name, I can call the metadata to get the source code (string). Then I compile that string and that Results in Method object that has and IEnumerable containing all of the code statements of that method. So I was to get the list of statements across all classes and methods.

```
        IXppcMetadataProvider serviceMetadataProvider = Program.getXppcMetadataProvider();

        IEnumerable<string> classNames = serviceMetadataProvider.ClassNames();

        MultipassAdministrator multipassAdmin = new MultipassAdministrator(serviceMetadataProvider);


        foreach (string className in classNames)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> classMethods = serviceMetadataProvider.ClassMethods(className);

            foreach (string methodName in classMethods)
            {
                string source = serviceMetadataProvider.GetClassMethodSource(className, methodName);

                Method method = multipassAdmin.CompileSingleMethod(source) as Method;

                if (method != null)
                {
                    foreach (Statement statement in method.Statements)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(statement.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use the following Linq methods that act like *higher order functions*

```
System.Console.WriteLine(
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                getXppcMetadataProvider().ClassNames().SelectMany(
                    className => getXppcMetadataProvider().ClassMethods(className)
                    .Select(
                        methodName => getXppcMetadataProvider()
                        .GetClassMethodSource(className, methodName)
                    ).Select(
                        source => new MultipassAdministrator(getXppcMetadataProvider())
                        .CompileSingleMethod(source) as mymeth)
                )
                .Where(method => method != null).SelectMany(
                    method => method.Statements
                ).Select(statement => statement.ToString())

               ));
```

`Select` when you have a 1 to 1 correspondence, as opposite to `SelectMany`, that would correspond to `bind` in Haskell.

Notice that is straightforward to get *function composition* in Linq, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks! I was close to that, but no sigar.. Your solution did it!

Answer (score 0):

Converting to the query syntax is easier, but LINQ is slower and harder to debug/comprehend.

```
var q = from nothing in new[] { 0 }
        let serviceMetadataProvider = Program.getXppcMetadataProvider()
        let classNames = serviceMetadataProvider.ClassNames()
        let multipassAdmin = new MultipassAdministrator(serviceMetadataProvider)

        from className in classNames
        let classMethods = serviceMetadataProvider.ClassMethods(className)

        from methodName in classMethods
        let source = serviceMetadataProvider.GetClassMethodSource(className, methodName)
        let method = multipassAdmin.CompileSingleMethod(source) as Method
        where method != null

        from statement in method.Statements
        select statement.ToString();

System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, q));
```